# For any pair of definable sets of the same cardinality, is there a definable bijection between them?

Tags: logic, model-theory

The answer is no. My question actually is, what are the sufficient and necessary conditions so that an arbitrary $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathcal{M}$ is rich enough to be able to define bijections between any two definable sets of the same cardinality?

---

I use these terms in this sense:

**$\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathcal{M}$**: It is an structure with domain $M$, with an associated set of named constants and another associated set of named relations.

**Definable set**: It is a subset of $M^n$, for any natural number $n$, that can be defined using logical formulas and the associated sets of constants and relations.

**Definable function**: A definable set, which contains only ordered pairs and $(x,y)\in f$ and $(x,z) \in f$ imply $y=z$.

---

Let's call the property of being able to define a bijection for any two definable sets of the same cardinality as *bijection-complete*. Here are some examples:

- The $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathcal{N}$ that has as domain $\mathbb{N}$, no constants, and only a one-placed relation $R(x)$ that holds if $x$ is even, is not bijection-complete, since we can define the sets of even numbers $\{x:R(x)\}$ and odd numbers $\{x: \lnot R(x)\}$ and the only definable function is the identity (be it ranging through all the naturals, just the evens or just the odds) $\{(x,x): x=x\}$
- If we add to the structure $\mathcal{N}$ of the previous point, the functions $S(x, y)=x+y$ and $M(x,y)=x*y$, the structure becomes bijection-complete. Given that we can define $0$ as the $\{x: \forall y[S(x, y)=y] \}$, and $1$ in a similar maner, we can start defining all the naturals and hence, be able to define any finite set and any bijection between finite sets. Furthermore, for any infinite definable sets $A$ and $B$ we can well order them ($x<y$ iff $\exists z [z \not = 0 \land S(x, z)=y]$), define their associated successor functions $S_A$ and $S_B$, and define the bijection by recursion.
- For the $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathcal{Q}$ that has as domain $\mathbb{Q}$, all it's elements named by a constant (the decimal expansion) and all the usual relations (if it's in a math textbook, we'll count it as included), it is not clear at all (to me) if it is bijection-complete. The definition by recursion of the previous point can no longer apply here given that a successor function can't be defined (because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense), and I see no straightforward way of (dis)proving bijection-completeness. Consider the difficulty of defining a bijection between $\{x: \text{the first three numbers of its decimal expansion sum 12} \}$ and $\{x: \text{in it's continued fraction form, the third element is a prime} \}$.

---

So again, what is needed for $\mathcal{M}$ to be bijection complete? How can it be proved that a certain $\mathcal{M}$ is or isn't bijection complete? (exhaustion or recursion as in $\mathcal{N}$ is not, in general, possible)

---

Edited: point 2 of examples and the definition of definable set

Comment: Note that bijection-completeness doesn't have to be a notion of richness: sufficiently *vacuous* structures may be bijection-complete by virtue of having very few definable sets. E.g. in $(\mathbb{Q};<)$, the only definable sets are $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{Q}$. (Incidentally, it may be more natural to consider definability *with parameters*, but the point still applies.)

Comment: Note that if there is a definable bijection between two definable sets in $\mathcal{M}$, then these two definable sets have the same cardinality in every structure elementarily equivalent to $\mathcal{M}$. So a necessary condition is that any two definable sets of the same cardinality in $\mathcal{M}$ have the same cardinality in any model of the complete theory of $\mathcal{M}$. This suggests a variant of your question: Which complete theories $T$ have the property that if two definable sets have the same cardinality *in every model of $T$*, then there is a definable bijection between them?

Comment: Unfortunately there are some imprecisions in your question. 1. By "logical formula", do you mean formula of first-order logic? Do you allow formulas with parameters from $\mathcal{M}$ (as in Noah's comment)? Do you only consider definable subsets of $\mathcal{M}$ (corresponding to formulas in one free variable) or definable subsets of $\mathcal{M}^n$ for all $n$ (corresponding to arbitrary formulas)? 2. The argument in your second example is not right. Assuming that "logical formula" means first-order logic, (continued...)

Comment: ... the structure $(\mathbb{N},R,S)$ does *not* define $<$, and can't carry out definitions by recursion in general. It's possible that this structure *is* bijection-complete, just because there are very few definable sets (I haven't thought about this carefully, but they should basically be Boolean combinations of finite translates of the even numbers, plus or minus finitely many elements). But not for the reason you gave.

Comment: 3. When you say $\mathbb{Q}$ with "the usual constants and the usual relations", what are these? It's common to consider $\mathbb{Q}$ as a linear order, an abelian group, a field, etc. In the rational field, you can define $\mathbb{N}$ and carry out definitions by recursion.

Comment: A bit off topic first: Oh my god Alex Kruckman, I'm the friend of Cristian Chavez that sent you the email yesterday, thanks for your answer!!! To the questions: 1. Yes, I mean only FOL. If by parameters you mean constants ($0$, $1$, $\pi$), yes. I meant $\mathcal{M}^n$, I'll edit that

Comment: What are "the usual constants and the usual relations" on $\mathbb Q$? In particular, is "is an integer" a usual relation?

Comment: 2. You are right, my bad. A two placed sum function is needed to define <. In that case my purported proof would work with a structure that has this 2-placed function, I'll edit that. 3. I meant that in some maximal term of the sense. It's fine if every element is named by a constant (it's decimal expansion) and the relations are maximal in a similar sense (all functions we can think of, less or greater than, is a solution of this polynomial, etc). If it is used in some area of math, I consider that as a "usual relation". That includes being an interger.

Comment: @Ryunaq Sorry to nitpick on the details of your interesting question. But example 2 is still not right. The structure $(\mathbb{N},+)$ still can't carry out definitions by recursion. Definitions by recursion are possible in first-order theories which can code finite sequences, but $(\mathbb{N},+)$ just isn't expressive enough to do this. To see the issue for yourself, try to write down an explicit definable bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $2\mathbb{N} \cup 3\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Ryunaq Well, [the theory of $(\mathbb{N}; +)$ is decidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic), so it can't possibly handle recursion in general.

Comment: @Alex On the contrary, I appreciate pointing out any errors, thanks! I realize now that if I want to use primitive recursion, at least as Gödel did it, I must have multiplication too. Is there any proof that coding can't be done with just $(\mathbb{N}, +)$? It seems intuitively true but I'd like to know how to prove it, do you know a textbook where I could see this? Also, as a fun fact, an explicit definable bijection for $2\mathbb{N} \cup 3\mathbb{N}$ can be written, just not as I expected.

Comment: @Ryunaq you're right! But not an order-preserving one, I think.

Comment: @Noah Thanks for the answer, you're right. It's because it's both decidable and complete, I really should re-read some arithmetic.

Comment: @Alex There is one! It goes like: If $x=4z$ or $x=4z+2$, then $y=x/2*3$; if $x=4z+1$, then $y=(3x+1)/2$; if $x=4z+3$, then $y=(3x-1)/2$. I'm almost sure that this partitioning works for any two definable sets, making $(\mathcal{N}, +)$ bijection complete. However I also think the straightforward induction on formulas won't work for this.

Comment: @Ryunaq Ah yes, that's nice.

Comment: If $\mathcal{M}=\mathbb{R}$, the two sets $\{(x,y):x=y\}$ and $\{(x,y):x\neq y\}$ are definable with the same cardinality, but most tractable languages $\mathcal{L}$ will not have enough resources to define a bijection.

Comment: Here is a non-trivial problem in point-set topology as a special case:  Suppose $\mathcal{L}$ is the uncountable first-order language with a function symbol for every continuous function from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Can a bijection between $\{(x,y):x=y\}$ and $\{(x,y):x\neq y\}$ be defined in $\mathcal{L}$?

Comment: The third example is bijection complete as long as the language for $\mathcal{Q}$ includes $+$ and $\times$.  By Julia Robinson’s theorem, we can define the integers in this structure, so we can also put the rationals in bijective correspondence with the integers, and pair off the members of any equally large subsets.